# Keep indentation in multi line variables when using replacetokens in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have this variable defined in my azure pipeline.

```
application.properties: |
    customMessage=This is dev machine
    customMessage2=This is dev machine2
```

I use the replacetokens task to replace patterns of style #{someVariable}# with the actual value.

I use it here:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: app-test-config
  namespace: xxx
data:
  application.properties: |
    #{application.properties}#
```

But this results in the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: app-test-config
  namespace: xxx
data:
  application.properties: |
    customMessage=This is dev machine
customMessage2=This is dev machine2
```

First line is ok but the rest has wrong indentation.

How can I make all rows have correct indentation

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `replacetokens@5` task can only replace value for multi-line variables but cannot keep indentation.

For this, we can opt to define multiple single-line variables in the pipeline instead.

```
variables:
  customMessage: This is dev machine
  customMessage2: This is dev machine2
```

And edit the target file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: app-test-config
  namespace: xxx
data:
  application.properties: |
    customMessage=#{customMessage}#
    customMessage2=#{customMessage2}#
```

The output is as expected.

Comment: Yes, that is my current workaround. I would much rather just type the configuration as a whole in the variable section.

Comment: Indeed, it is simply a workaround and I don't think it supports indentation in our scenario as of now. For this, you may also leverage the [support link](https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task/issues) of the extension task and probably report the current limitation/suggestion with their maintainers. Would you consider accepting the current workaround, which may help others with similar concerns? Thx.